# Why is this missile positioned in this odd position? How can it be launched correctly?

Tags: fighter, jet

[image]

How this missile is positioned here in this odd position? How this can be launched right from this jet?

Comment: What "missile" in that picture are you talking about? I don't see any attached to that jet... Are you asking about the ones on the side? Near the canopy?

Comment: A [freehand red circle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775) indicating what missile you're asking about would add considerable clarity to this question.

Comment: I see like 6 different things here that look like missiles or things that could be mistaken for missiles. Which thing are you looking at?

Answer (score 70):

You're seeing the Sidewinder on the folded up wingtip of the F-18 that is in the foreground out of frame except for its wing tip and missile sticking up at the bottom.  The airplane is between the camera and the adjacent F-18 who's canopy is visible.  The long lens being used foreshortens and compresses everything distance wise so it looks like the missile is 6 inches from the canopy when it's actually probably 20-30 ft closer to the camera.

Comment: Thanks. Curiosity killed, tranquility prevailed.

Comment: This answer is as decisive as a sidewinder!

Comment: @keshtopat , don't forget to "tick" correct answers; if you do so it gives you points and allows you to ask more and more great questions like this.

Comment: Note that the sidewinder is slightly out of focus (compare to the canopy) - this gives away the foreshortening.  We could work out how much closer from the dimensions in reality vs in pixels (as I suggest [in this old answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/61014/2559), but here we've got more to go on)

Comment: It's also identical to the same thing on the plane behind it.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica Not quite - the one in the background has a blue stripe, indicating an inert training missile.  The foreground missile has a yellow stripe and brown stripe, indicating a live warhead and rocket motor, respectively.

Comment: You can also see somebody's hand in between the missile and the wingtip, just in front of the yellow stripe, so it's presumably being serviced in some way at the moment...

Comment: So, essentially [this](https://fas.org/man/dod-101/sys/ac/f-18-hornetinhungary.jpg), but from another angle...?

Comment: Yes, but I'm really curious to know from where the shot was taken.  It looks like the taxiing aircraft is moving up to the catapult, so the camera is somewhere to the port side of the ship, toward the bow end.  It makes me think it was taken from the rescue helicopter that normally hovers near the ship during cat launches, using a long telephoto lens.

Comment: @JohnK The long lens impression is added to by the similar apparent length of the portions of the two missiles that can be seen despite the necessary difference in distance between them. Linear shortening with distance is pronounced when the photo is taken from not far behind the closest aircraft. With a long lens the absolute differnces are not very different so linear dimensions appear similar.

Comment: @JohnK, I believe that shot is taken from the island looking forward, and the Hornet is taxiing aft.  It's a little tough to confirm because it is cropped severely, but I think the markings to the left are of the landing area.  Take a look at the photo here for a comparison of the perspective I think this was taken from:  https://www.military.com/daily-news/2019/08/20/e-2d-hawkeye-aircraft-takes-out-4-super-hornets-carrier-repairs-underway.html